# Validating if text exists on a jQuery wrapped set

Tags: jquery

Basically I have a jQuery wrapped set and a date and what I want is to validate if the date does not exist on the wrapped set.

What I am trying is the following:

```
    var selectedTourDate = $("#tourDate").val();

    var isDateBooked = $("#bookedTourDate *").each(function () {
        if (this.innerHTML == selectedTourDate) return true;
        else return false;
    });

    if (isDateBooked) alert("Date invalid");
```

But the isDateBooked contains some sort of function:

> jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]

How would the correct way to accomplish this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `isDateBooked` is a jQuery object, which will always return true. You need to test the `.length` of a jQuery object to determine if there's anything interesting inside of it.

I think what you want to do is replace `.each` with [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), and then test the length of the resulting jQuery object:

```
var selectedTourDate = $("#tourDate").val();

var $isDateBooked = $("#bookedTourDate *").filter(function () {
    if (this.innerHTML == selectedTourDate) return true;
    else return false;
});

if ($isDateBooked.length) alert("Date invalid");
```

Comment: return this.innerHTML == selectedDate; :)

Comment: Yep, that works even better. (Typically I try to correct an OP's code without optimizing it, so it's easier to see what was broken.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:contains()` selector and `length` property:

```
var selectedTourDate = $("#tourDate").val();
var isDateBooked = $("#bookedTourDate *:contains("+selectedTourDate+")").length:
if (isDateBooked) alert("Date invalid");
```

Comment: Both solutions work exactly the same, and they are basically the same principle. Thank you very much. I think I rather use filter. +1 for a working solution.